# Bash Script to Count Number of times script has run

Tags: bash, cgi

So I need a bash script that will display the number of times the script has been run. I obviously need an environment variable but I am having trouble figuring this out. Note: This is on a web server in a CGI file and I basically want it to count the number of times the "page" is loaded (a counter).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

An environment variable (like any variable in CGI really) won't really cut it since this data is lost once the script terminates.

The most common way to store a count is to use a database via calls available in your language (like DBI for Perl); your website provider should provide a number of such methods.

I suppose you could actually execute a client to connect to and query the database just like you would from the commandline.

Lacking that, and assuming the script has write access to some directory on the machine, you could store it to a file:

```
#!/bin/bash

file="magic_path/count.cnt"

if [ -e ${file} ]; then
    count=$(cat ${file})
else
    count=0
fi

((count++))

echo ${count} > ${file}

echo Loaded ${count} times
```

Bear in mind that such scripts could be prone to errors which you (or I) might have overlooked. Worth noting is the comment below by @James_R_Ferguson, pointing out the [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#File_systems) in my example.

Comment: Strictly speaking there is a class race condition here.  For correct counts you need an exclusive lock guarding the counter file.

Comment: Brilliant point; I can't think of a way to do this, assuming all you've got to work with is the lonely CGI script and no backend.

Comment: @garmen : A simple Perl script with an exclusive, lock using the Fcntl module should suffice, I think.

Comment: That's true, but assuming you have to do it with Bash (without calling perl! :D) How would fcntl be used here anyway? Perhaps you could point me to more information.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of options:

1. Try flock. See the [manpage for details](http://linux.die.net/man/1/flock).
2. Create a temporary directory at a fixed location and use it as the lock since directory creation is atomic.
3. If you can be guaranteed that when you actually check the count nothing else will be running, then you could append to a file to increment the count: `echo -n . >> $LOGFILE`. Then you could (while guaranteeing that nobody else was accessing it) check the size of the file to determine the actual count.

An example of #2:

```
TEMPDIR_LOCK=/path/to/fixed/lock/dir
mkdir $TEMPDIR_LOCK
while [[ $? != 0 ]] ; do
    # sleep, usleep, or busy loop
    mkdir $TEMPDIR_LOCK;
done

# read and increment count in some file

rm -f $TEMPDIR_LOCK
```

Comment: Very nice. I wasn't aware of Linux's flock() and would have used Perl.